# Recursive function to add up all of the digits in a number

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a function that adds up all of the digits in a number, and to keep adding up digits until the number is reduced to a single digit. For example, the number `99999999999` should be evaluated like this:

```
99999999999
9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9
99
9+9
18
1+8
9
```

However, when I try running the number `99999999999` through my function, it returns `7`, even though it should return `9`. I've gone over my code several times, and I can't think of any reason why.

Here's the code:

```
sumdr x
  | x <= 9 = x
  | otherwise = sumdr $ addupnums x

addupnums y = foldl (+) 0 $ map read1 $ show y

read1 :: Char -> Int
read1 '1' = 1
read1 '2' = 2
read1 '3' = 3
read1 '4' = 4
read1 '5' = 5
read1 '6' = 6
read1 '7' = 7
read1 '8' = 8
read1 '9' = 9
read1 '0' = 0
read1 x = error "needs to be a number"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine for me on a 64-bit system. If you're on a 32 bit system, 99999999999 doesn't fit into an Int, so it will overflow and give you wrong results.

If you change the type to Integer, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

**[Edit]**

If you are only interested in the result of the repeated application until one digit remains, of course Daniel Fischer is right, and you should use his solution. It might be still instructive how to deal with this kind of problem if such a shortcut isn't possible, hence I leave my old answer.

**[/Edit]**

You got the answer, but two remarks:

- Using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle) you could have found the function `digitToInt` in `Data.Char`, which is your `read1`
- Transforming a number to a string just to get the digits seems to be wasteful, when a little bit more math will work as well, e.g.

.

```
f 0 = 0
f y = (y `mod` 10) + f (y `div` 10)
```

Or the slightly cryptic version:

```
f = sum . map (`mod` 10) . takeWhile (> 0) . iterate (`div` 10)
```

If you're really concerned with speed, you can use `divMod`, and you can try if accumulators are faster, e.g.

```
f n = go n 0 where
  go 0 s = s
  go k s = go k' (s+s') where (k',s') = k `divMod` 10
```

Comment: Or the efficient version: `sumdr 0 = 0; sumdr n = case mod n 9 of { 0 -> 9; m -> m; }`.

Comment: I will definitely be using Hoogle in the future. However, your first solution takes a lot more time to load than my solution with big numbers (I'm going to check the second solution right now).

Comment: @Landei. Hi.. i have just started on haskell.. so my interpretation may not be correct.. but i ran your ist solution and point free style on the number 64 and it gave an output of 10.. but is the question to keep adding the digits till you get a single digit number??